# Count String in a String Using Datatype Char

Tags: string, count, char

Good day everyone! I have the codes for such a problem where, to create a program that counts how many times the second string appears on the first string. Yes it counts if you put 1 letter only, but if you put 2, it is an error. As an example. If the first string is Harry Partear, and the second string is ar, it must count as 3. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
char first [100], second;
int count;

cout <<"Enter 1st String: ";
cin.get (first, 100);

cout <<"Enter 2nd String: ";
cin >> second;

for (int i = 0; i < strlen (first); i++)
{
    if (tolower(first[i]) == tolower(second))
    {
                          count++;
                          }
                          }


cout << "THE STRING " << "'" << second << "'" << " appeared " << count 
<< " times in "     << first << ".";

getch ();
return 0;
}
```

Hope anyone can help me. :(

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that your `second` variable is declared like a single `char`, not like a string. This is what it should be:

```
char first[100], second[100];
```

The `[100]` before `second` applies to `first`, not to `first` and `second`, even though the two are declared as part of a single declaration. The type of `second` remains scalar `char`.

Now that `second` is a character array, let's solve the second problem: you need to treat `second` like an array, too. In particular, you need to add a nested loop to go over `second`, so that the comparison looks like

```
if (tolower(first[i]) == tolower(second[j]))
```

`j` is the index of the nested loop.

Finally, you need a flag to indicate that all characters of `second` were matched against characters of `first`. Set this flag to `true` before the nested loop, then set it to `false` when you find a mismatch. If the flag remains `true` after the loop, increment `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing it, like this way:

```
char first [100], second[100];
int count;

cout <<"Enter 1st String: ";
cin.get (first, 100);

cout <<"Enter 2nd String: ";
cin.get (second, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen (first); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen (second); i++)
    {
        if (tolower(first[i]) == tolower(second[j]))
        {
                          count++;
                          }
                          }
                          }
```

But the problem now is that, the program does not prompt the user to input the second string. Sad. Hahaha. :(